# How to use this special operator?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Given that $m$, $n$ are non-zero integers and the following formula, 
how would you find the value of $5 \otimes 7$.

[Image of equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJlyZ.jpg)

Comment: whatever that is, it's not the Kronecker product.

Comment: There are a couple ambiguities. Does the $2m = n$ rule take precedence over the $m < n$ rule? And in $n = m$, do we add $3$ to $n$ before taking the product? Because if we do multiplication and then addition, we'll have an infinite loop and the function will not be well-defined on the diagonal.

Comment: With the caveats hinted by Larry B., apply recursively the definition. And use MathJax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.